# How to automatically exit rtorrent after completing a download?

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

My intention is to execute another command after rtorrent shows "done" message. For example I want to run:

```
rtorrent example1.torrent ; wget example2.mp4
```

But after the file is downloaded it doesn't kill the rtorrent process so the next command never executes unless I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

I am using rTorrent 0.9.4/0.13.4 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you solve that issue ? In short you need to monitor yr torrent session by creating a special session directory that records the download progress (`mkdir ~/.rtorrent.session`) and configuring yr `~/.rtorrent.rc` file with `session = ~/.rtorrent.session`.  Monitoring that download progress will allow you to kill yr `rtorrent` process when appropriate. This can be nicely put together in a short script.

Comment: If you did solve that issue, please provide an answer below and check it with a green mark to "accept" it.